# Vimeo upload errors

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to upload a video to vimeo.com.
I am getting an error messages for the required parameter, "upload.size". 
Here is the code:

```
let Vimeo = require('vimeo').Vimeo;
   let client = new Vimeo('##################################',
     '*****************************************',
     '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$');

   client.upload(
      {videoFile},
     {
       'name': videoName,
       'description': videoDescription,
       'upload.size': '139824438',
       'locale':   "en",
       'content_rating': ["safe"],
       ...
       'upload.approach': 'tus',
 },
```

I have tried rendering the size as an integer (139824438), but I received the same error.

Everything else seems to be ok.

Here is the error message:

```
[Error: {
    "invalid_parameters": [
        {
            "field": "upload.size",
            "error_code": 2002,
            "error": "Something strange occurred. Please try again.",
            "developer_message": "The required body is missing from request."
        }
    ],
    "error": "You have provided an invalid parameter. Please contact developer of this application.",
    "link": null,
    "developer_message": "The parameters passed to this API endpoint didn't pass Vimeo's validation. Please check the invalid_parameters list for more information.",
    "error_code": 2204
}]
```

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake. 
The videoFile should not be in brackets.